# Setting timer for online exam using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, css, html, timer

I am trying to set a "Timer" for my online exam page using html and JavaScript where you can see code below.
 But I have problems:

Problem :

a) I need to show the time on fixed time where exam should complete on fixed time .If examiner is not able to complete the exam in time, then the page  should show  alert message about **"Time up"** and must show the last page of total answer that user has attempted,grade and time that user has finished the exam.

b)we can see running as following **"Your Left Time is :1 Minutes :53 Seconds"** at the bottom of my page where I have kept **min=1** .But it show like this **Your Left Time is 0 Minutes :59 Seconds** because I have kept min=1

c) Here I want to show the perfect time with hours,minutes and seconds where in future if there any changes in hours,minutes and sec.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fs6xaeox/

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UFT-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">


<script>
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;

var questions = [
        [ "Which of the following a is not a keyword in Java ?", "class", "interface", "extends", "C" ],

    [ "Which of the following is an interface ?", "Thread", "Date", "Calender", "A" ],

    [ "Which company released Java Version 8 ?", "Sun", "Oracle", "Adobe", "A" ],

    [ "What is the length of Java datatype int ?", "32 bit", "16 bit", "None", "C" ],

    [ "What is the default value of Java datatype boolean?","true","false","0","A"]
];
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

function renderQuestion(){
    test = _("test");

    var showscore=Math.round(correct/questions.length*100);


    if(pos >= questions.length){
        document.getElementById("online_start").src = "animatedthankyou.gif";

        test.innerHTML = "<h3>You got "+correct+" correct of "+questions.length+" questions</h3>";
        test.innerHTML += "<h3> Your Grade : "+showscore +"% </h3>";
        test.innerHTML +="<h4>Exam Finished in Time:" + sec+" Seconds</h4>";
        test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='EndExam()'>End the Exam</button>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "<h3>Test Completed</h3>";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;



        clearTimeout(tim);
        //document.getElementById("endtime").innerHTML = "<h4>Finished Time:"+min+" Minutes :" + sec+" Seconds</h4>";
        document.getElementById("starttime").style.display += 'none';
        document.getElementById("showtime").style.display += 'none';
        //document.getElementById("showtime").style.display += 'block';


        return false;
    }
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "<h3>Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length+"</h3>";
    question = questions[pos][0];
    chA = questions[pos][1];
    chB = questions[pos][2];
    chC = questions[pos][3];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Next</button><br><br>";


}
function checkAnswer(){
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    choice=-1;
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
        if(choices[i].checked){
            choice = choices[i].value;
        }
    }
    if(choice == questions[pos][4]){
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
}

window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);


function EndExam(){

location.href="Loginpage.htm";
}


    var tim;
       var showscore=Math.round(correct/questions.length*100);
        var min = 1;
        var sec = 60;
        var f = new Date();
        function starttime() {
            showtime();
            document.getElementById("starttime").innerHTML = "<h4>You started your Exam at " + f.getHours() + ":" + f.getMinutes()+"</h4>"; 
        }
        function showtime() {
            if (parseInt(sec) > 0) {
                sec = parseInt(sec) - 1;
                document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = "Your Left Time is :"+min+" Minutes :" + sec+" Seconds";
                tim = setTimeout("showtime()", 1000);
            }
            else {
                if (parseInt(sec) == 0) {
                    min = parseInt(min) - 1;
            document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = "Your Left Time is :"+min+" Minutes :" + sec+" Seconds";
                    if (parseInt(min) == 0) {
                        clearTimeout(tim);
            alert("Time Up");


            /*_("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
            test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
            test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+showscore +"% out of "+questions.length+"</h2>";
            test.innerHTML = "<button onclick='EndExam()'>End the Exam</button>";
            pos = 0;
            correct = 0;
            clearTimeout(tim);
            document.getElementById("endtime").innerHTML = "You Finished exam at Time is :"+min+" Minutes :" + sec+" Seconds";
            document.getElementById("starttime").style.display += 'none';
            document.getElementById("showtime").style.display += 'none';
            //document.getElementById("showtime").style.display += 'block';
            return false;*/

                        window.location.href = "Loginpage.htm";
                    }
                    else {
                        sec = 60;
                        document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = "Your Left Time is :" + min + " Minutes :" + sec + " Seconds";
                        tim = setTimeout("showtime()", 1000);
                    }
                }

            }
        }




</script>
</head>

<body onload="starttime()" >

<div id="Holder">
<div id="Header"></div>
<div id="NavBar">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="Loginpage.htm"> Login</a></li>
<li><a href="Registrationpage.htm">Registration</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div id="Content">
<div id="PageHeading">
<h1><marquee direction="right" behavior="alternate">All the Best</marquee></h1>
</div>

<div id="ContentLeft">
<h2></h2><br>
<img id="online_start">
<br>
<h6>Online Examination System(OES) is a Multiple Choice Questions(MCQ) based 
examination system that provides an easy to use environment for both 
Test Conducters and Students appearing for Examination.</h6>
</div>
 <div id="ContentRight">
<section class="loginform_cf">
<table>
    <tr>
          <td id="test_status"  style="text-align:left" ></td>
          <td id="starttime"    style="text-align:right"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td id="test" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>

</table>    
<div id="showtime" ></div>
</section>
</div>

</div>


<div id="Footer">Developed by - K.P.RAJU</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

can any help for this problem.

Comment: please create a demo

Comment: updated fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/fs6xaeox/4/   totalsec introduced, min and sec is calculated from totalsec

Comment: Be careful, everyone can read the answers to your questions. They just have to open the developers tools..... I would advise to do the checking of the correct answer on the server side, and limit the checking of a correct answer per user to once.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you might be better using either PHP, or using a program for the testbuilding. This is simply because I can trick the timer by either inputting my own time left, or bypassing the time's up portion. And trust me as a student when I say that if this is discovered, you will literally never get your tests.

Here you are specifying that they only have 60 seconds left, as you call the value of sec when displaying the time, rather than the actual current time

```
            else {
                sec = 60;
```

Supposed to be time?

```
   tim = setTimeout("....
```

I may have missed other things, so do get back and tell me if I was any way helpful

Comment: Also, might want to add an "Unanswered" value, in the event they do not complete it in time. And for ease of getting their responses, grades, time start (maybe even date), and time finish (ditto date), you may want to have the data set to a MySQL Database, offered by most WebHosts

Comment: Also, set your page redirects to actual webpages, as unless this file is running within the same directory on your webserver, it will return 404 errors. And can you better rephrase "C"

Answer (score 1):

just to be safe take notice of that everyone can manipulate the time here and see full answers. If this is just a pre check for subsribe to a course then this is a "good" way. But don't use this for live exams.

**A, show time to complete**

make use of library to add seconds, and so to display

```
  var showcurtime = moment();
  var curtimeformat = showcurtime.format('h:mm:ss a');
  var showendtime = showcurtime.add(totalsec, 's');
  var endtimeFormat = showendtime.format('h:mm:ss a');

  console.log(curtimeformat);
  console.log(endtimeFormat);
```

**B, show time left**

keep total time and subtract in beginning of function showtime()

**C format time**

I suggest you use moment.js to format the time. dont reinvent the wheel. to display the time you can use this syntax

```
moment().format('h:mm:ss a');
```

I adjust your fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/fs6xaeox/13/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping the timer problem. But the below functionality  is not working properly .It is not the displaying the starttime and endtime. so help me display both

Comment: function starttime() {
            showtime();
            var showcurtime = moment().format('h:mm:ss a');
        var curtimeformat = showcurtime.format('h:mm:ss a');
        var showendtime = showcurtime.add(totalsec, 's');
        var endtimeFormat = showendtime.format('h:mm:ss a');
        document.getElementById("starttime").innerHTML = "<h4>You started your Exam at " + curtimeformat + "</h4>";

        document.getElementById("endtime").innerHTML = "<h4>You should finish on your Exam at " + endtimeFormat + "</h4>";
  
  
  
            
        }

Comment: in the fiddle you do see the start and endtime, i adjust fiddle to put end time on different row

Comment: It is working in fiddle but it is not working in html page and Browser I can't see the starttime and endtime

Comment: what is this moment.js ?

Comment: where to use this moment.js I did not get any code about this

Comment: a i added a reference in fiddle . http://momentjs.com/ just download the javascript and reference in yout html. momentjs is a javascript library Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks now its working .But I want to diplay time  at the end of test completed  at what time the examiner as completed like this:
"Exam Finished in Time:___Minutes___ Seconds."

Comment: updated fiddle.. also added extra check in showtime to stop the time!